# how to change upgrade android jellybean

Tags: updates

I have just bought spice mi 504 and I want its android jellybean to upgrade to android kitkat. I have tried to root the phone in order to upgrade it but it don' t even root nor it shows any update option what should I do

Answer (score 0):

Look, this is about your phone `Rom Region`, it means, **if** kitkat Update availabe *for your Rom Region* or *your country ip* , then you can update the phone.**(OTA Update)**

**else ;**

if the update availabe for manual flash (or install) just find the rom you need from below link then flash (or install it)

[**Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?**](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/where-can-i-find-stock-or-custom-roms-for-my-android-device)

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the phone don't have official update from the manufacturer, also there is always ROM s made by developers to solve This kind of issues. 
To install this ROMs you need to flash, unlock and root your device, this is not an easy job specially the first time, I recommend go to website called xda developers "Google it"  and search for your mobile exact model number, you will fine many people explain how to do and how, you should be really Patient or geek, this may teak up to ten hours for the whole process.